# How do I know if my list has all 1s?

Tags: python

I am looking for a better way, may be using list comprehensions?

```
>>> x = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> x
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> for i in x:
...   if i!=1:
...     print "fail"
... 
>>> 
>>> x = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
>>> for i in x:
...   if i!=1:
...     print "fail"
... 
fail
>>>
```

Comment: Do you care what the result is when the list is empty, ie `x = []`?

Comment: @jimhark If the list is empty, then proposition "every element of the list equals one" is [vacuously true](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Comment: @PeterOlson, yeah, I understand that. And in general reducing an empty list should return the identity element for the reduction function, which for `and` is `True`. I was asking the original poster if he cared.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
>>> x = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> all(el==1 for el in x)
True
```

This uses the function [**`all`**](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#all) with a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions).

---

If you always have only zeroes and ones in the list (or if you want to just check if the list doesn't have any zeroes), then just use **`all`** without any additional tricks:

```
>>> x = [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
>>> all(x)
False
```

---

**Benchmark** of some solutions:
<sub>The numbers mean what time **in milliseconds** it took to run the solution once (average of 1000 `timeit` runs)</sub>

Python 3.2.3

```
              all(el==1 for el in x): 0.0003 0.0008 0.7903 0.0804 0.0005 0.0006
                       x==[1]*len(x): 0.0002 0.0003 0.0714 0.0086 0.0045 0.0554
         not([1 for y in x if y!=1]): 0.0003 0.0005 0.4142 0.1117 0.1100 1.1630
                set(x).issubset({1}): 0.0003 0.0005 0.2039 0.0409 0.0476 0.5310
y = set(x); len(y)==1 and y.pop()==1:   WA   0.0006 0.2043 0.0517 0.0409 0.4170
                   max(x)==1==min(x):   RE   0.0006 0.4574 0.0460 0.0917 0.5466
                 tuple(set(x))==(1,):   WA   0.0006 0.2046 0.0410 0.0408 0.4238
not(bool(filter(lambda y: y!=1, x))):   WA     WA     WA   0.0004 0.0004 0.0004
                              all(x): 0.0001 0.0001 0.0839   WA   0.0001   WA
```

Python 2.7.3

```
              all(el==1 for el in x): 0.0003 0.0008 0.7175 0.0751 0.0006 0.0006
                       x==[1]*len(x): 0.0002 0.0003 0.0741 0.0110 0.0094 0.1015
         not([1 for y in x if y!=1]): 0.0001 0.0003 0.3908 0.0948 0.0954 0.9840
                set(x).issubset({1}): 0.0003 0.0005 0.2084 0.0422 0.0420 0.4198
y = set(x); len(y)==1 and y.pop()==1:   WA   0.0006 0.2083 0.0421 0.0418 0.4178
                   max(x)==1==min(x):   RE   0.0006 0.4568 0.0442 0.0866 0.4937
                 tuple(set(x))==(1,):   WA   0.0006 0.2086 0.0424 0.0421 0.4202
not(bool(filter(lambda y: y!=1, x))): 0.0004 0.0011 0.9809 0.1936 0.1925 2.0007
                              all(x): 0.0001 0.0001 0.0811   WA   0.0001   WA
```

[PyPy 1.9.0] Python 2.7.2

```
              all(el==1 for el in x): 0.0013 0.0093 0.4148 0.0508 0.0036 0.0038
                       x==[1]*len(x): 0.0006 0.0009 0.4557 0.0575 0.0177 0.1368
         not([1 for y in x if y!=1]): 0.0009 0.0015 175.10 7.0742 6.4390 714.15 # No, this wasn't run 1000 times. Had to time it separately.
                set(x).issubset({1}): 0.0010 0.0020 0.0657 0.0138 0.0139 0.1303
y = set(x); len(y)==1 and y.pop()==1:   WA   0.0011 0.0651 0.0137 0.0137 0.1296
                   max(x)==1==min(x):   RE   0.0011 0.5892 0.0615 0.1171 0.5994
                 tuple(set(x))==(1,):   WA   0.0014 0.0656 0.0163 0.0142 0.1302
not(bool(filter(lambda y: y!=1, x))): 0.0030 0.0081 0.2171 0.0689 0.0680 0.7599
                              all(x): 0.0011 0.0044 0.0230   WA   0.0013   WA
```

The following test cases were used:

```py
[] # True
[1]*6 # True
[1]*10000 # True
[1]*1000+[2]*1000 # False
[0]*1000+[1]*1000 # False
[random.randint(1, 2) for _ in range(20000)] # False
```

`WA` means that the solution gave a *wrong answer*; `RE` stands for *runtime error*.

---

So my verdict is, *Winston Ewert*'s `x==[1]*len(x)` [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13615438) is the fastest in most cases. If you rarely have lists of all ones (the data is random, etc.) or you don't want to use additional RAM, my solution works better. If the lists are small, the difference is negligible.

Comment: `There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.`

Comment: @RohitJain And then you needed 30 seconds per character to write your comment :P

Comment: @phant0m.. hah ;) Went somewhere after answering.

Comment: +1. This is clear and correct. I thought I might have a faster way, but I was wrong.

Comment: @sampson-chen found an approach that *can* be faster. I'm writing it up now.

Comment: I disagree on the verdict. The `x==[1]*len(x)` is not necessary the best, but the fastest. For readability purposes I would suggest the all(el==1 for el in x). So best just depends on where you are optimizing for. (Btw, if you are using python and care about such a small perfomance improvements, you are using the wrong language)

Comment: @BlaXpirit But you finished by declaring the fastest method 'the best'.

Comment: @BlaXpirit `bitarray(x).all()` Can you add this approach? I'd like to see it compared against the other methods.  here's a link to the [bitarray module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/), though it will only work on an array of 0's and 1's.

Comment: @BlaXpirit, if you revisit this, and are taking requests, please add `not([y for y in x if y !=1])`. It's the list comprehension version of @ckb's idea, has good performance for some cases and is correct for all cases. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterSmit, The meaning `all(el==1 for el in x)` is very clear to me because it maps almost directly to the problem statement. But I also find `x==[1]*len(x)` readable and easy to understand. Frankly, the reason this didn't jump to mind is I had wrongly assumed instantiating the list would be slower. "Small performance improvement?" For some of the test cases the top contenders performance differs by and order of magnitude. I don't think that's small at all. And yes, performance is not the only or overriding concern, but it shouldn't be ignored either, especially for something this fundemental

Comment: @BlaXpirit, also @Nabb posted a fix to the set approach: `set(x).issubset({1}).

Comment: @BlaXpirit, great work filling out the performance picture: solution * test case * Python version. I've learned a few things and really find the differences between versions interesting and instructive.

Comment: @daydreamer I wrote a program specially for this answer. I have a list of strings with code, a list of tuples with data and correct answers, `eval` and `timeit` each with each. Well, it's a bit more complicated than that...

Answer (score 42):

Yet more possible methods:

```
x == [1] * len(x)

list(set(x)) == [1]

tuple(set(x)) == (1,)
```

Some timing results:

```
all(el==1 for el in x)                   [1.184262990951538, 1.1856739521026611, 1.1883699893951416]
y = set(x);len(y) == 1 and y.pop() == 1  [0.6140780448913574, 0.6152529716491699, 0.6156158447265625]
set(x) == set([1])                       [0.8093318939208984, 0.8106880187988281, 0.809283971786499]
not(bool(filter(lambda y: y!=1, x)))     [1.615243911743164, 1.621769905090332, 1.6134231090545654]
not any(i!=1 for i in x)                 [1.1321749687194824, 1.1325697898864746, 1.132157802581787]
x == [1]*len(x)                          [0.3790302276611328, 0.3765430450439453, 0.3812289237976074]
list(set(x)) == [1]                      [0.9047720432281494, 0.9006211757659912, 0.9024860858917236]
tuple(set(x)) == (1,)                    [0.6586658954620361, 0.6594271659851074, 0.6585478782653809]
```

And on PyPy because: why not?

```
all(el==1 for el in x)                   [0.40866899490356445, 0.5661730766296387, 0.45672082901000977]
y = set(x);len(y) == 1 and y.pop() == 1  [0.6929471492767334, 0.6925959587097168, 0.6805419921875]
set(x) == set([1])                       [0.956063985824585, 0.9526000022888184, 0.955935001373291]
not(bool(filter(lambda y: y!=1, x)))     [0.21160888671875, 0.1965351104736328, 0.19921493530273438]
not any(i!=1 for i in x)                 [0.44970107078552246, 0.509315013885498, 0.4380669593811035]
x == [1]*len(x)                          [0.5422029495239258, 0.5407819747924805, 0.5440030097961426]
list(set(x)) == [1]                      [1.0170629024505615, 0.9520189762115479, 0.940842866897583]
tuple(set(x)) == (1,)                    [0.9174900054931641, 0.9112720489501953, 0.9102160930633545]
```

Comment: `x == [1]*len(x)` i hadn't thought of that one, that's ingenious.

Comment: `bitarray(x).all()` can you put this up, too?  Under my testing (i offloaded the import to the setup since it's a one time cost), it even beats `x == [1]*len(x)` by about six percent.

Comment: @WinstonEwert +1, this answer belongs at the top

Comment: I'm surprised that `x == [1]*len(x)` is so fast.

Comment: I would argue that the `set` answers here and in other answers are incorrect as they return false for the empty list. This is of course easily fixed by using `{1} >= set(x)` (or `set(x).issubset({1})`).

Comment: The timing results here seem biased to me. What is `x`? A long list of ones, I bet, which is the worst case for the `all...` solution.

Comment: @BlaXpirit, yes all ones. My theory was that was the worst case scenario for all methods, so it made sense to measure it. More complete benchmarking should try other options as well.

Comment: @Nabb should the answer to the question `Python: how do I know if my list has all 1s?` be true when `x` is the empty list? I would interpret that to be vacuously false when `x` is empty: think of it this way: "Does [] have all 1s?" - No, it has no 1s.

Answer (score 16):

In addition to the `all()` answer already provided, you can also do it with `set()`:

```
>>> x = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> y = set(x)
>>> len(y) == 1 and y.pop() == 1
True

>>> a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
>>> b = set(a)
>>> len(b) == 1 and b.pop() == 1
False
```

**Caveat; (and Redeeming Factor)**:

- As some have pointed out, this is less readable; however...
- I'll leave this up since:

  - As the results in @WinstonEwert's answer demonstrate, this solution can perform better than the `all()` solution proposed by @BlaXpirit
  - I think most members of StackOverflow prefer to learn new things; alternative solutions contribute to that end by prompting discussion, inquiry, and analysis.

Comment: You can, but why would you want to?

Comment: If there are any clear disadvantages to this solution that I don't realize, I'd totally welcome learning something new; but I didn't think StackOverflow discouraged the discussion of alternative solutions.

Comment: It's going to be less efficient as it has to go through all of the elements to make a set before doing the check (no short-circuiting), and it's also far, far less readable.

Comment: @Lattyware, it can be hard to tell what's less efficient unless you test. This approach, cleaned up a bit can be more efficient in general for lists up to 20 elements and it's worst case timing is always better. Code doesn't look good in a comment so I'm posting an answer with more information.

Comment: +1. This answer is correct and unique with a performance profile that is beneficial in many cases. I hope down voters reconsider.

Comment: It return false if x=[] . It should return true. (I didn't downvote because it's answer is still interesting)

Comment: @MatthieuW: I considered that briefly before. Should it it return true if `x=[]`? The question is `Python: how do I know if my list has all 1s?`. If the list is the empty list, I would interpret it to be vacuously false.

Comment: @sampson-chen See Peter-Olson comment on the question. x=[] returns true is more consistent. In actual problem, the empty case may be meaningless or be a special case where false is required.

Comment: @MatthieuW: Thanks, I read that comment but I felt that it ought to be vacuously false; maybe someone in this post will eventually enlighten us on the semantics.

Comment: @sampson-chen, my answer now has a section "Vacuous Truth and Reduction of an Empty List" that presents one way to think about degenerate cases.

Comment: @jimhark thanks for that, Jim, but I was more referring to the language / interpretation side of things. If someone gave you an empty basket and asked you: "are all the kittens in this basket orange?" - what would be the most appropriate answer?

Answer (score 10):

@sampson-chen had a good idea that could use some help. Consider up voting his answer and look at this this as an extended comment. (I don't know how to make code look good in a comment). Here's my rewrite:

```
>>> setone = set([1])
>>> x = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> set(x) == setone
True
```

This code does not *exactly* match the original question because it returns `False` for an empty list which could be good or bad but probably doesn't matter.

### Edit

Based on community feedback (thanks @Nabb), here is a second rewrite:

```
>>> x = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> set(x).issubset({1})
```

This properly handles the case where x is an empty list.

I think this is readable. *And* the variant part is faster as written (almost twice as fast). In fact, on my Python 2.7 system, it's always faster for lists up to 20 elements and for lists that are all 1's. (Up to 3 times faster.)

### Update: Vacuous Truth and Reduction of an Empty List

@Peter Olson wrote in a comment:

> If the list is empty, then proposition "every element of the list equals one" is [vacuously true](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Further discussion in the comments lead up to @sampson-chen writing:

> I felt that it ought to be vacuously false; maybe someone in this post will eventually enlighten us on the semantics. – sampson-chen

Let's see what Python thinks:

```
>>> all([])
True
```

Well then how about:

```
>>> any([])
False
```

So why is that right? If you haven't run into this before it might be confusing. There's a way to think about that may help you understand and remember.

Let's back up a little bit and start with:

```
>>> sum(mylist)
```

Python's built-in function `sum` sums items of an iterable from left to right and returns the total. Thinking more abstractly, `sum` reduces an iterable by applying the addition operator.

```
>>> sum([])
0
```

The sum of nothing is 0. That's fairly intuitive. But what about this:

```
>>> product([])
```

Okay, it *actually* returns a name error because `product` doesn't exist as a built-in function. But what *should* it return? 0? No, the value of an [empty product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product) is 1. That's most mathematically consistent (click the link for a full explanation), because 1 is the [identity element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) for multiplication. (Remember `sum([])` returned 0, the identity element for addition.)

Taking this understanding of the special role the identity element plays, and returning to the original problem:

```
all([])
```

Is equivalent to reducing the list using the [Boolean `and` operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_and). The identity element for `and` is True, so the result for the empty list is `True`.

```
any([])
```

The identity element for `or` is `False`, the same as the value of this expression.

Answer (score 2):

This goes through the list and collects any terms that aren't 1. If those terms exist, then bool returns True and the answer is False.

```
not(bool(filter(lambda y: y!=1, x)))
```

Comment: As soon as you use a lambda, ``filter()`` is probably slower than a list comprehension, and this inefficient as it doesn't short circuit. It's also horribly unreadable.

Comment: +1 for a good approach, but I prefer the list comprehension version for it's objective 3.5x speed improvement and subjective increased readability. `not([y for y in l if y !=1])` with the 3.5x speed improvement makes it twice as fast as @BlaXpirit's `all(el==1 for el in x)` for some common cases. If you're wondering why the double negative `!=`/`not`, this gives the correct answer for an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Some console examples using `all()`'s cousin `any()`:

```
In [4]: x = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

In [5]: not any(i!=1 for i in x)
Out[5]: True

In [6]: x = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
In [7]: not any(i!=1 for i in x)
Out[7]: False
```

Comment: How about this list: `[0,2]`?

Comment: It seems really weird to reverse the logic for no reason.

Comment: There are an unlimited number of ways you *could* do this, but `all(i==1 for i in x)` is the most direct, natural and explicit. Here you've essentially phrased the test as "There is not an element in x that is not equal to one." instead of simply "Every element in x is equal to 1." Yes, they are logically equivalent, but why needlessly take the option that is more verbose and uses a double negative?

Comment: @Lattyware It runs faster than `all()` on my system for large lists, it's bad I got -1 even for a correct answer. o.O

Comment: ``all()`` also short circuits. There is no difference.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I didn't -1 you (the opposite in fact), I think it's not as good as the ``all()`` answer, but it's definitely valid.

Comment: @Lattyware In terms of readability and simplicity, I'd say YES `all()` version is better and clearer , but there's no harm in showing an alternative.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Just because an answer is valid does not mean it is useful. `all()` solves the problem better so what purpose is served by posting an inferior answer? Also, I tested this on my machine and for sufficiently large lists all() turned out to be faster, not any().

Comment: @MarkAmery This definitely doesn't deserve a lower score than sampson-chen's which is an actively *bad* answer as opposed to just not being the best.

Comment: @MarkAmery Well looking at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion), I didn't find anything like "I can't post an inferior answer", and also read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer), which clearly states that **Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative**. and I think my answer is a viable alternative, I am sorry If you're not impressed by my answer.

Comment: I didn't vote on either post, but I wouldn't call this a viable alternative, much rather a pointless one.

Comment: @sampson-chen had a good idea. With a small improvement in implementation it is faster in some situations including the exact example provided in the original question. Please find it in your heart to un-down-vote him. His answer was correct and unique with a performance profile that is beneficial in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

how about this :

```
lo = min(L)
hi = max(L)
if (lo != 1) and (hi != 1) and (lo != hi):
   print "fail"
```

Comment: Or, shortened: `max(x)==1==min(x)`

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way is:

```
arr = [1,1,1,1]
len(arr) == sum(arr) #True if arr is all 1's
```